# Problem with importing UDF (User Defined Function) in Spark for Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a problem when I try to import udf using:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
```

The characters "udf" have a strike through them in the Scala IDE window.Everything compiles fine! I am using Spark 3.1.2 and Scala 2.12

[A picture of the problem!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7JGD.png)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Hi @ChlamRises. Are you using the udf function in your code? If not try adding a call to it, which may remove the strikethrough that might be warning that it’s currently unused.

Comment: Hi man! Yeah I am... it's very strange!

Comment: Is it possible you're getting a deprecation warning? See [here in one of the overloaded definitiions of udf](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L5388).

Do you get any message when you hover over `udf`?
Could you include the output of `sbt compile`?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. I get nothing when hovering over udf... What do you mean by "include the output of sbt compile"?